# Sql using OR condation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi lets assume i have below sample data

```
Service_ID  Service_RNO Cust_Name   Agrement_ID Cust_ID Service_Date    Next_Service
4                004    customer1   35           16     2016-01-03      2016-02-02
5                005    customer1   35           16     2016-02-03      2016-03-01
```

and if i have the below query that check if `Next_Service` is not in `Service_Date`

```
SELECT  dbo.Service.Service_ID, 
        dbo.Service.Service_RNO, 
        dbo.Customer.Cust_Name,
        dbo.Service.Agrement_ID,
        dbo.Customer.Cust_ID,
        dbo.Service.Service_Date,
        dbo.Service.Next_Service 
FROM dbo.Service 
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Service.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID 
WHERE  Next_Service between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-06' 
AND    Next_Service not in (
          SELECT Service_Date 
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
) 
ORDER BY Next_Service
```

output of above query will be the second record

Note that `Service_Date` values in most cases is entered same as `Next_Service` value in previous record for that customer

but i have some cases where `Service_Date` is entered after one or two days

so i tried to use the blow query to solve the issue i have

```
SELECT  dbo.Service.Service_ID, 
        dbo.Service.Service_RNO, 
        dbo.Customer.Cust_Name,
        dbo.Service.Agrement_ID,
        dbo.Customer.Cust_ID,
        dbo.Service.Service_Date,
        dbo.Service.Next_Service 
FROM dbo.Service 
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Service.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID 
WHERE  Next_Service between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-06' 
AND    Next_Service not in (
          SELECT Service_Date
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
) 
or    Next_Service not in (
          SELECT Dateadd(d, -1, Service_Date) 
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
) 
ORDER BY Next_Service
```

output of above query should be empty, but the output I get is the two records what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your WHERE condition. The first row won't satisfy the first part of condition, that is

```
Next_Service between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-06' 
AND    Next_Service not in (
          SELECT Dateadd(d, 1, Service_Date) 
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
)
```

but passes the second part

```
or    Next_Service not in (
          SELECT Dateadd(d, 1, Service_Date) 
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
)
```

What you probably want to do is

```
WHERE  Next_Service between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-06' 
AND (Next_Service not in (
          SELECT s.Service_Date
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID) 
     OR Next_Service not in (
          SELECT Dateadd(d, -1, s.Service_Date) 
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID)
)
```

(Notice the parenthesis)

Or do it completely differently:

```
WHERE  Next_Service between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-06' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
            AND Next_Service BETWEEN Dateadd(d, -1, s.Service_Date) AND s.Service_Date)
```

Comment: hi that was error in query i updated the query still have the issue

Comment: same as in the question

Comment: Also I've noticed you don't use s.Service_Date in your subquery, but only plain Service_Date, which is probably a problem as well.

Comment: the query u provided give the second record  also tried with SELECT Dateadd(d, -1, Service_Date)  same issue the query should not return any vales thanks

Comment: added SELECT s.Service_Date same issue

Comment: You didn't add the parenthesis as in my answer. You are doing A && B || C, but really you want to do is A && (B || C)